# When raycasting forms multiple intersections, which point does it return? Can which point is returned be controlled?

Tags: game-physics, godot, gdscript

I'm working on a chess "game" in Godot where players can import 3D models for the board and wrap a checkerboard around it with uv coordinates. All the conversions between world, local, and uv space required for this project have been crazy. But, one of the more unexpected caveats with complex board shapes, particularly my freshly imported klein bottle, is that raycasting a line from the camera will theoretically have multiple solutions, but only return one.

When the player clicks on the screen, I think raycasting should find the intersection closest to them, but Godot's [PhysicsDirectSpaceState.intersect_ray()](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsdirectspacestate.html#class-physicsdirectspacestate-method-intersect-shape) method is returning whichever intersection it finds first. This intersection could either be the correct one or not, and with up to 4 intersection points with the klein bottle, the chances are slim that the correct intersection is returned. The [RayCast](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_raycast.html?highlight=RayCast#class-raycast-method-get-collision-point) object does the same thing, only storing one intersection point.

**Is there a way to return all the intersection points of a ray/line in Godot?** That way I could sort through them to find the closest intersection point to the Player node. I also feel like this shouldn't be an issue in the first place. [Godot's Ray-Casting](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/ray-casting.html) tutorial describes the ray as "hitting something" when it returns a values, and that intuitively tells me that the closest intersection to the "ray origin" argument will be returned.

If you have the stomach for work-in-progress spaghetti code, I have a [GitHub project](https://github.com/Roboticy3/Mess) with all the source code on it. And here is the code I use whenever I raycast in the game:

```
#cast out a ray from the camera, given a physics state s
static func raycast(var p:Vector2, var c:Camera, 
    var w:World, var v:float = INF, var mask:int = 0x7FFFFFFF):
    
    #get physics state of the current scene
    var s = w.direct_space_state
    #origin and normal of the camera
    var o:Vector3 = c.project_ray_origin(p)
    var n:Vector3 = c.project_ray_normal(p)
    #get ray intersection with that scene
    var r = s.intersect_ray(o, n * v, [], mask)
    #if the intersection lands, return r
    if !r.empty():
        return r
    return null
```

Above from [BoardConverter.gd](https://github.com/Roboticy3/Mess/blob/main/Objects/Board/BoardConverter.gd), line [472](https://github.com/Roboticy3/Mess/blob/main/Objects/Board/BoardConverter.gd#L472).

Comment: The klein bottle is a single collider, right? The way we would usually go over multiple ray intersection is by adding them to the exclude array, but that does not help with multiple intersections with the same collider. I would also expect it to return the nearest intersection. Does switching between GodotPhysics and Bullet make any difference?

Comment: Yes, its a single collider. I'll try Bullet physics, is there a class in Godot that uses it or is it an external library? Do you mean a literal bullet as in a moving RigidBody? That could *really* give my game a homemade feel now that I think about it :P

Comment: Go to Project (menu) -> Project Setting -> General (tab) -> Physics -> 3d -> Physics Engine, there you can change it. The default is Bullet. However, the integration with Godot is not the best, and GodotPhysics has come a long way. To the point that I expect less bugs with GodotPhysics. Edit: I suppose you could always throw a projectile at it :P

Comment: With your raycast, aside from which collider it hit, do you need the position, or do you need the UV? If you need the UV we can work around the raycast issue with a secondary `Viewport`.

Comment: I was reading through my code and I remembered: I get the uvs through a *slightly* roundabout method of compressing a virtual copy of the mesh into the camera plane and finding the triangle that surrounds the part of the plane that was clicked on... It's def the source of the issue, so I'm working on that now. Still keeping the rock throwing idea. Not closing the issue yet bc I might still be wrong, should be handled in about an hour.

Comment: I posted an answer, I don't know if it is what you are looking for, but if you only need the raycast for the UV, it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could render to a hidden `Viewport` and query that.

So let us start by adding a `Viewport` to your scene. Make sure it has a size set. In fact, we can resize to match the main `Viewport` with a script. For example:

```
extends Viewport


func _ready() -> void:
    # warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
    get_tree().connect("screen_resized", self, "resize")


func resize() -> void:
    size = get_viewport().size
```

Alternatively:

```
extends Viewport


func _ready() -> void:
    # warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
    get_viewport().connect("size_changed", self, "resize")


func resize() -> void:
    size = get_viewport().size
```

Also make sure to set `render_target_update_mode` to `UPDATE_ALWAYS`. Set `render_target_v_flip` to true, and Set `transparent_bg` to `true`.

Then you can add a `Camera` child with a script that copies the `global_transform` of the main `Camera`, and make it `current` (under the `Viewport` node). For example:

```
extends Camera


func _ready() -> void:
    current = true


func _process(_delta: float) -> void:
    global_transform = get_tree().root.get_camera().global_transform
```

You might also want to copy all the relevant properties of the camera to make sure the view matches:

```
    var tracked_cam:Camera = get_tree().root.get_camera()
    global_transform = tracked_cam.global_transform
    fov = tracked_cam.fov
    keep_aspect = tracked_cam.keep_aspect
    cull_mask = tracked_cam.cull_mask
    environment = tracked_cam.environment
    h_offset = tracked_cam.h_offset
    v_offset = tracked_cam.v_offset
    doppler_tracking = tracked_cam.doppler_tracking
    projection = tracked_cam.projection
    fov = tracked_cam.fov
    size = tracked_cam.size
    frustum_offset = tracked_cam.frustum_offset
    near = tracked_cam.near
    far = tracked_cam.far
```

And what you want to render in that `Viewport` is your mesh, but with a different material. So you are making a duplicate of your `MeshInstance`, and you can either:

- Add it as a child of the original, and use `layers` (under "VisualInstance" in the Inspector Panel) of the `MeshInstance` and `cull_masks` of the `Camera` to make sure only the `Camera` in the `Viewport` can see it.
- Or, add it as a child of the `Viewport`, do something similar to what we did for the `Camera`, so it copies the position of the original, and set `own_world` to `true` on the `Viewport`, so it only renders what is inside of it.

About the material, it will be a `ShaderMaterial` that outputs the UV as color (write `ALBEDO`, and set the shader as `unshaded`):

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode unshaded;

void fragment()
{
    ALBEDO = vec3(UV, 0.0);
}
```

Then in a script attached to some other `Node`. It will have a `export var` of type `Texture` and set it to a new `ViewportTexture` from the `Viewport` you defined it:

```
export var texture:Texture
```

We want to make sure that the `Viewport` is already in the scene tree when this `Node` enters. And it can find it. Thus, this `Node` should not be the `Viewport`, nor a parent of the `Viewport`. Also avoid using a child of the `Viewport`. Thus, we want a sibling. And a sibling that is before the `Viewport` in the scene tree.

Now, to read a pixel from the `Texture`, you can get an `Image` from it with `get_data`, then call `lock` on it, and then use `get_pixel` or `get_pixelv`. Don't forget to `unlock` it.

This code should work for both mouse or touch input:

```
func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if not (
        event is InputEventScreenDrag
        or event is InputEventScreenTouch
        or event is InputEventMouse
    ):
        return

    var image:Image = texture.get_data()
    image.lock()
    var color := image.get_pixelv(event.position)
    if color.a != 0.0:
        print(Vector2(color.r, color.g))

    image.unlock()
```

Comment: I don't think this can work with my current Node setup, but all the numbers check out, so I'm trying a Viewport-based implementation

Comment: For some reason, the Image object is being generated as null for me, do you have any idea as to why this could happen? I've tried initializing the texture as a ViewportTexture instead of just a Texture, and have been following your steps thoroughly.

Comment: @PabloIbarz Were you getting any errors? The most common issue I run into with `ViewportTexture` is that it has to be local to the scene. And that might throw a wrench on it if you are using an scene instance to do it. I also remember getting null if I put the `Viewport` in a `ViewportContainer`. Edit: also double check it is getting the correct size.

Comment: I'll try enforcing that the texture is local to the scene. I was getting an error when working with the image because texture.get_data() is returning null

Comment: @PabloIbarz Ok, something else I didn't pay attention to: Put the `Viewport` before the `Node` that uses its texture in the scene tree. So when it loads it finds it. I suppose that is not the issue you found, yet I think I skipped that on the answer. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Yeah, since I wanted this to be a utility, I set up the nodes and tried to write the function statically, which didn't work. I ended up making something completely different after a while. I'm sure this solution would work on a blank project, but it's exams month so I can't really verify that, and my project has a lot of questionable design choices that make this a pain in the butt to implement no matter what my approach is.

Comment: Hey! I came back to this and it turned out all I needed was a better node tree setup.
It works better than I could have ever imagined, and I'm not even done optimizing it. Its a bit late to say this but thanks for the advice.